# Grails: g:render pass data

Tags: grails

I'm having problems to pass data through g:render to another view, which is included in printme.gsp

printme.gsp:

```
<h1>abc</h1>
${input1Instance?.number} <!-- Here I can see the right value -->
<g:render contextPath="../input1" template="form"/>
```

input1/_form.gsp:

```
<!-- Here there is no value set -->
<g:textArea maxlength="1000" name="number" value="${input1Instance?.number}"/>
```

How can I pass the Object from printme.gsp to input/_form.gsp?

Thanks.

Comment: My answer was exactly same as @ErnestoCampohermoso's and I think we both posted exactly at the same time, so I had to delete my answer to avoid discrepancies and unwanted down votes. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must pass the data as model explicitly:

```
<g:render contextPath="../input1" template="form" model="[input1Instance:input1Instance]"/>
```

then you can access it from template